# How do I get my RegistryBuilder to be Autowired into feign's HttpClientFeignLoadBalancedConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, feign, mutual-authentication, openfeign

I am trying to achieve a mutual TLS connection to an endpoint that we connect to using a feign client with apache httpclient underneath.

I attemped this configuration, that does not work, it just terminates with a `handshake_failure` message and as far as I can tell it just doesn't use my keystore at all during the request. My analysis is that it's because `.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLConnectionSocketFactory())` and `.setConnectionManager(connectionManager)` don't play well together in this configuration:

```
@Primary
public Client feignClient(
    CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory cachingFactory, SpringClientFactory clientFactory,
    BeanFactory beanFactory, 
    @Qualifier("customApacheHttpClient") ApacheHttpClient apacheHttpClient) {
    return new TraceLoadBalancerFeignClient(apacheHttpClient, cachingFactory, clientFactory, beanFactory);
}

/**
 * @param connectionManager is autowired from HttpClientFeignLoadBalancedConfiguration.HttpClientFeignConfiguration
 */
@Bean(name = "customApacheHttpClient")
public ApacheHttpClient apacheHttpClient(
    HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager,
    FeignHttpClientProperties httpClientProperties) {
    RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(httpClientProperties.getConnectionTimeout())
        .setRedirectsEnabled(httpClientProperties.isFollowRedirects())
        .build();
    return new ApacheHttpClient(
        HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLConnectionSocketFactory())
            .build());
}
```

---

As a solution I have removed `setSSLSocketFactory` and instead added a RegistryBuilder bean, however it does not seem to be picked up. How can I get this bean:

```
@Bean
public RegistryBuilder registryBuilder(SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory) {
    return RegistryBuilder.create()
        .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
        .register("https2", sslConnectionSocketFactory)
        .register("https", sslConnectionSocketFactory);
}
```

Injected into here:

```
package org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon;

import ...

class HttpClientFeignLoadBalancedConfiguration {
  ...
    protected static class HttpClientFeignConfiguration {
    ...
        @Autowired(required = false)
        private RegistryBuilder registryBuilder;

...
```

Any pointers are welcome, or any GitHub project that sets up TLSv1.2 with client-side certificates feign and ApacheHttpClient would be very helpful.